# Can Google's GWT be hacked?

Tags: gwt, libgdx

I'm planning to make a multiplayer card battle game using Libgdx for the web, it uses the GWT engine for web deployment.

Is this engine secured? Can it be hacked? I don't want to waste my time learning it only if it will be hacked later on.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"Can it be hacked?"_, but you might be interested in [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurity.html).

Answer (score 3):

There is no engine as such. GWT compiles Java code to javascript which is then downloaded and run in the browser. By default this is obfuscated. It is difficult to modify but as the code is available in the browser it is theoretically possible to reverse engineer and modify it.

GWT puts no restrictions on how you implement server side web application code. It provides libraries to help with client to server RPC which you may choose to use or not. That means the server side security is down to you and is as secure as you want to make it.

Comment: Pauli, I have revisited this question because I recently found some other browser based engines using WebGL. I'm planning to make an online game but I fear that users might be able to run scripts in real time or anything that will allow them to manipulate data. I'm planning to have a ranking system of how well they played which will be saved in database. Is it advisable to use webgl based engines? OR should I use engines like Adobe Flash, Unity etc.

Thanks

Comment: Ah nevermind, i found this question which basically answered all my questions. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13799/is-webgl-a-security-concern

Thanks!